# While loop not working - code written to determine income tax

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on this code to calculate the income tax in Python.

The `while` loop is not working. Can anyone find the error in this code?

```
database1 = ["bob","cic","dod","viv","gog"]

def incometax(r):
    nam = input("Please provide your name: ")

# if database1.find(nam) == "true":
    if nam in database1:
       counter = 0
       while counter < 1:
         try:
            r = input("Please provide your income details: ")
            counter += 1
            if r > 500000:
                if r > 600000:
                    if r > 700000:
                        if r > 800000:
                            return str('Rs.') + str(int((r - 800000)*.3)) + str(' is your income tax')
                        return str('Rs.') + str(int((r - 700000)*.25)) + str(' is your income tax')
                    return str('Rs.') + str(int((r - 600000)*.2)) + str(' is your income tax')
                return str('Rs.') + str(int((r - 500000)*.1)) + str(' is your income tax')
            else:
                return('You are exempt from Income tax')
         except:
            counter == 0
            return("Please do not type in special character")


        # print(counter)
    else:
      return('Your name is not in the records')

    print(incometax("r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to force the result from input() to a nunmber this way:

```
r = float(input("Please provide your income details: "))
```

Also, just to clarify, your loop, as is, seems to be set to run for only one time. This is what you intend?

Maybe what you intended is that on "except", the function kept asking for values. Unfortunately this won't happen because you have a return, which will make the while loop exit

Comment: I had put the return to take care of "error" issues and then return back to the same field wherein income has to be entered. Not possible in return function??

Comment: Not really, return will stop the execution of your function. What you might want to do is print the message in the except instead of returning it. This might keep your while loop asking, until it reaches a valid return condition.

Comment: Also, instead of 'counter ==0' just before that return, I think that you meant 'conuter = 0'

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

At first glance, I saw:

- `if database1.find(nam) == "true":` This will never happen. The result of a Boolean expression is never a string. You could compare it to the value `True`, but you can as well omit the comparison altogether and write `if database1.find(nam):`. But that doesn't matter as you use the alternative (and better) `if nam in database1`.
- The `counter` is not needed. If you `return` as soon as you have a definite result (be it valid or not), you as well can have a `while True:` loop which loops forever unless it is terminated from inside (which happens on `return` and other events).
- Don't return in the `except` clause - **this seems to be your original issue.** Once you return, you leave your `while` loop and it seems to be dysfunctional.
- If you are on Python 3, your `r` becomes a string. You shouold it pass through `float()` to turn it to a float. On Python 2, what you do works, but is a security hole. Better do `float(raw_input(...))` instead.
- The parameter `r` and the argument `"r"` you are passing are quite useless.
- `except:` should not be used. Instead, catch only the exception you are expecting there.
- `str('whatever')` is pointless; `'whatever'` already is a `str()`.
- You are returning a string from the function which should calculate the income tax. This is valid, but not good programming. Better return the value itself and let the caller handle the processing.

  You could do it like this:

  ```
  import sys
  if sys.version < (3, 0):
      input_function = raw_input
  else:
      input_function = input

  def tax_from_income(r):
      if r > 800000:
          return int((r - 800000)*.3)
      elif r > 700000:
          return int((r - 700000)*.25)
      elif r > 600000:
          return int((r - 600000)*.2)
      elif r > 500000:
          return int((r - 500000)*.1)
      else:
          return 0

  def incometax():
      nam = input("Please provide your name: ")

      if nam in database1:
          while True:
              try:
                  r = float(input_function("Please provide your income details: "))
                  tax = tax_from_income(r)
                  if tax > 0:
                      return 'Rs.' + str(tax) + ' is your income tax'
                  else:
                      return 'You are exempt from Income tax'
              except ValueError:
                  print("Please do not type in special character")
                  # while loop is continued here...
  ```